# How to programmatically put focus on floating label in Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, material-design

I am making a form in AngularJS and this is how it looks[image]
How do I remove the label when the input is disabled. but it should come when I click on it.

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label has-success">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" ng-model='driver.firstName' ng-disabled="!edit" ng-focus="true">
<label for="form_control_1">Firstname</label>
<span class="help-block">Enter your First name</span>
</div>
```

This is the HTML code.

Comment: Are you talking about placeholder? (see https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInput#api-param-section)

Comment: No, the floating label. Label which goes up when you type something.